# Prevent Window Location Movement On Hash Tags (With Jquery Tabs)

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, anchor

Ok, i know theres plenty of previously asked questions, discussing this topic however i'm at a loss and haven't been able to figure it out.

**My Problem** is that when i click on each tab link the whole browser window moves to the anchor of the tab content `div` as you would expect on something like a scrollTop link for example. Does anyone know of a quick fix?

I'm using a basic tab structure like this:

```html
<div id="tabContaier">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tabDetails">

  <div id="tab1">
    <h1>My Tab Title</h1>
    <p>Whatever goes here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

My Jquery is the following:

```js
$(".tabContents").hide();
$(".tabContents:first").show();

$("#tabContaier ul li a").click(function(){

  var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".tabContents").hide();
  $(activeTab).fadeIn();
});
```

As always, any help greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean the jump to the top of the page when you click on an anchor with a hash as its href attribute?

If you wanted to stop this you would have to prevent the default action on your click handler. here is an example:

```
$("#example").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 

  //Add your code here
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is enough, jQuery takes care of the compatibility matters.

Comment: Also, this selector is very inefficient. `$('#example')` is just *way* faster.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your browser is following the `href` of the tab ... you need to prevent that by doing the following :

```
$("#tabContaier ul li a").click(function(event){
   // your code
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

[Docs for event.preventDefault() here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: @Sam no idea ... unless the OP wants the browser location to be updated but also prevent scrolling ...

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me if it does not worked

```
<div id="tabContaier">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1" onclick="return false;">Tab 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use onclick, its frowned upon as it does not separate design from script.

Comment: @Sam, Thats true if you are really doing some business login on click. Its just a `return false` statement. Thats perfectly fine to have it here. When next time you come back and view the link's HTML you'll get to know that the link's onclick returns false hence the link won't get visited.